Authentification with Django REST Framework and JWT (CustomUser)
I am working on a Django project to connect Patients and Doctors. I am trying to implement token authentication using Django REST Framework and djangorestframework-simplejwt. Here is my model:from django.db import modelsfrom django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManagerfrom django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
def create_user(self, email, username, password=None, **extra_fields):if not email:raise ValueError('l email est oblicatoire')email = self.normalize_email(email)user = self.model(email=email, username=username, **extra_fields)user.set_password(password)user.save(using=self._db)return user
```

```
def create_superuser(self, email, username, password=None, **extra_fields):
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
    return self.create_user(email, username, password, **extra_fields)
```

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):email = models.EmailField(unique=True)username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)photo=models.ImageField(upload_to='image/')is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

```
groups = models.ManyToManyField(
    Group,
    related_name='custom_user_set',  # Add related_name to avoid clashes
    blank=True,
    help_text='The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.',
    verbose_name='groups',
)
user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
    Permission,
    related_name='custom_user_set',  # Add related_name to avoid clashes
    blank=True,
    help_text='Specific permissions for this user.',
    verbose_name='user permissions',
)


USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

objects = CustomUserManager()

def __str__(self):
    return self.email
```

```
class Patient(CustomUser):
nom = models.CharField(max_length=50)
prenom = models.CharField(max_length=50)
telephone = models.CharField(max_length=16)`enter code here`
genre = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=[('H', 'Homme'), ('F', 'Femme')])
adresse = models.TextField()
```

I also specified the AUTH_USER_MODEL in the settings
My problem is that, I would like to allow through the custom user that patients and doctors can authenticate without problem.
Ps: I'm a beginner.

please write in english so everyone can understand...!
